# Testing React with mocha with --watch option, shows warnings only the first time

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js

I'm testing a React component with mocha. I'm trying to catch some warnings (through `console`), mostly related to "Failed propType" and other warnings that React can give. However I've had to recur to other methods of testing since the test will only show warnings the first time.

Here's my test code:

```
var jsdom = require('mocha-jsdom');
var { expect, assert } = require('chai');
var sinon  = require('sinon');


describe('Deck', function() {
    jsdom();

    var React = require('react/addons');
    var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
    var Deck, Card, OtherMock; 
    var renderer, result;

    beforeEach(function() {
        Deck = require('../App/Components/Deck.js');
        Card = require('../App/Components/Card.js')
        OtherMock = React.createClass({ render: function() { return null } });

        renderer = React.addons.TestUtils.createRenderer();

        renderer.render(
            <Deck>
                <OtherMock />
                <OtherMock />
                <OtherMock />
                <Card />
                <Card />
                <Card />
            </Deck>
        );

        result = renderer.getRenderOutput();

    });

    afterEach(function() {
    });

    it('should create a new instance of Deck', function () {
        expect(result).to.exist;
    });

    it('should have a default style', function () {
        expect(result.props.style).to.exist;
    });

    it('should only allow children of type Card', function () {
        expect(result.props.children.length).to.exist;
        expect(result.props.children.length).to.equal(3);
    });


    it('should allow one card', function() {
        var renderer = React.addons.TestUtils.createRenderer();

        renderer.render(
            <Deck>
                <Card />
            </Deck>
        );

        var result = renderer.getRenderOutput()
        expect(result).to.exist;
        expect(React.Children.count(result.props.children)).to.equal(1);

    });

    it('should render empty when passed incorrect children', function() {
        var renderer = React.addons.TestUtils.createRenderer();

        renderer.render(
            <Deck>
                <OtherMock />
            </Deck>
        );

        var result = renderer.getRenderOutput()
        expect(result).to.exist;
        expect(React.Children.count(result.props.children)).to.equal(0);

    });

    it('should render when empty', function() {
        var renderer = React.addons.TestUtils.createRenderer();

        renderer.render(
            <Deck />
        );

        var result = renderer.getRenderOutput()
        expect(result).to.exist;
    });

    it('should add keys to children', function() {
        var index = React.Children.count(result.props.children);
        React.Children.forEach(result.props.children, function(child) {
            expect(child.props.cardIndex).to.exist;
            expect(child.props.cardIndex).to.equal(--index);
        })
    });

    it('should have just the first child with handlers');

    it('should have only the first and second child with images');

    it('should preload up to the determined number of images');

})
```

What I see is that for the first time to run (typing `npm run test` which just calls `mocha --watch --compilers js:babel/register --recursive`) it shows warnings and I'm able to mock `console.warn` with sinon and everything:

[image: first time]

However the second time, I don't get any warnings and the tests I do with a `console.warn` spy will fail.

[image: second time]

Any idea what is going on here? I've tried reaching out in mocha's Gitter, in IRC's React channel, going through the docs and through `mocha --help`, but no avail.